# does heroku supports nodejs with fastify?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, netlify, fastify

im trying to hit my heroku nodejs app with fastify instead express with my netifly react app but i get a CORS error.

been trying installing some packages but no with no lucky.

have anyone got into this sort of problem before?
netlify hitting heroku node api?

edit:

```
// create the server
const fastify = Fastify({
  ignoreTrailingSlash: true,
  trustProxy: true,
  logger: {
    genReqId: createRequestId,
    level: "info"
  }
});

// Use Header
fastify.register(fastifyCors, {
  // put your options here
  origin: "*",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
  allowedHeaders: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers",
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: true,
  maxAge: 86400
})
```

error on netlify react app while trying to hit nodejs with fastify in heroku:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://asd.herokuapp.com/api/images_type/slider' from origin 'https://qwerty.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   Blockquote

Also if I wanted to hit https://asd.herokuapp.com/api/images_type/slider should throw me an array but throwns an error on the heroku app, but deploy is successfull. so i dont know

Comment: How do you have CORS configured currently in your NodeJS API?

Comment: i have edited the first post. thanks for answering

Comment: Looks like you have it configured right. What does the error from Heroku look like?

Comment: I updated the first post with the error log, thanks !!

Comment: Your `allowedHeaders` should be an array of strings

Comment: that didnt worked @ManuelSpigolon already tried it

Comment: could you add a response header list you get calling heroku?